# homestead.yaml file not showing up

Tags: bash, laravel, homestead

homestead.yaml file not showing up

I really don´t understand it anymore.

I´m trying to install homestead but when I exec the following commmand:

> bash init.sh

The homestead.yaml file doesn't show up!?

In the documentation of laravel I read this:

Once you have cloned the Homestead repository, run the bash init.sh command from the Homestead directory to create the Homestead.yaml configuration file. The Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead hidden directory:

> bash init.sh

But the file isn't there. I'm working on a mac. Seriously searched the hole internet but can't find a solution.

I see this in my terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-name:homestead name$ bash init.sh
overwrite /Users/name/.homestead/Homestead.yaml? (y/n [n]) y
overwrite /Users/name/.homestead/after.sh? (y/n [n]) y
overwrite /Users/name/.homestead/aliases? (y/n [n]) y
Homestead initialized!
```

EDIT:

When I ls .homestead I see this:
[image]

Comment: As per the documentation,  the `Homestead.yaml` file is created inside `.homestead` hidden directory. What is the result of `ls .homestead`?

Comment: @sjsam please see my edit. But why is it hidden?

Comment: is the result the output of `ls .homestead`. Please make it clear in the question.

Comment: @sjsam oke I've done that

Comment: can you do a `ls ~\.homestead` please? It seems that in latest version, the `.homestead` is created in the home directory.

Comment: It looks like you have overridden the edit I have made to the question. ;) Any updates with this.

Comment: When I do ls ~\.homestead it's telling me: "No such file or directory". So I've installed it on the wrong place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99056/discussion-between-sjsam-and-jamie).

Answer (score 0):

If you passed the Homestead Initialization you are ready to go!
Run your Terminal and type:

```
cd $HOME
cd .homestead
nano Homestead.yaml
```

You will run the .homestead.yaml hidden file. Once you open it you can set up your configuration.

Thanks!